# SSE Java 11+ client example (w/o dependencies)

Tags: server-sent-events, java-http-client

I'm looking for examples using a plain JDK11+ http client reading server sent events, without extra dependencies. I can't find anything about sse in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) either.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 11 based implementation of SSE (Server-sent Events) client here:
[SSE Client](https://github.com/CiscoSE/commons-networking#sse-client)

It provides a pretty simple usage of processing of SSE messages.

Example usage:

```
EventHandler eventHandler = eventText -> { process(eventText); };
        SSEClient sseClient = 
SSEClient sseClient = SSEClient.builder().url(url).eventHandler(eventHandler)
    .build();
sseClient.start();
```

Note: I am the author of this SSE client.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT 1:** Info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Event_stream_format) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/#dispatchMessage) on the format of the incoming data.

**EDIT 2:** Updated the code sample to handle the `data:` part of the protocol. There are also `event:`, `id:`, and `retry:` parts (see links above), but I do not plan to add handling for those.

I can't find an official `BodySubscriber` to do SSE, but it's not that hard to write one. Here's a rough impl (but note the TODOs):

```java
public class SseSubscriber implements BodySubscriber<Void>
{
    protected static final Pattern dataLinePattern = Pattern.compile( "^data: ?(.*)$" );

    protected static String extractMessageData( String[] messageLines )
    {
        var s = new StringBuilder( );
        for ( var line : messageLines )
        {
            var m = dataLinePattern.matcher( line );
            if ( m.matches( ) )
            {
                s.append( m.group( 1 ) );
            }
        }
        return s.toString( );
    }

    protected final Consumer<? super String> messageDataConsumer;
    protected final CompletableFuture<Void> future;
    protected volatile Subscription subscription;
    protected volatile String deferredText;

    public SseSubscriber( Consumer<? super String> messageDataConsumer )
    {
        this.messageDataConsumer = messageDataConsumer;
        this.future = new CompletableFuture<>( );
        this.subscription = null;
        this.deferredText = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe( Subscription subscription )
    {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        try
        {
            this.deferredText = "";
            this.subscription.request( 1 );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            this.future.completeExceptionally( e );
            this.subscription.cancel( );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext( List<ByteBuffer> buffers )
    {
        try
        {
            // Volatile read
            var deferredText = this.deferredText;

            for ( var buffer : buffers )
            {
                // TODO: Safe to assume multi-byte chars don't get split across buffers?
                var s = deferredText + UTF_8.decode( buffer );

                // -1 means don't discard trailing empty tokens ... so the final token will
                // be whatever is left after the last \n\n (possibly the empty string, but
                // not necessarily), which is the part we need to defer until the next loop
                // iteration
                var tokens = s.split( "\n\n", -1 );

                // Final token gets deferred, not processed here
                for ( var i = 0; i < tokens.length - 1; i++ )
                {
                    var message = tokens[ i ];
                    var lines = message.split( "\n" );
                    var data = extractMessageData( lines );
                    this.messageDataConsumer.accept( data );
                    // TODO: Handle lines that start with "event:", "id:", "retry:"
                }

                // Defer the final token
                deferredText = tokens[ tokens.length - 1 ];
            }

            // Volatile write
            this.deferredText = deferredText;

            this.subscription.request( 1 );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            this.future.completeExceptionally( e );
            this.subscription.cancel( );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError( Throwable e )
    {
        this.future.completeExceptionally( e );
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete( )
    {
        try
        {
            this.future.complete( null );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            this.future.completeExceptionally( e );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Void> getBody( )
    {
        return this.future;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```java
var req = HttpRequest.newBuilder( )
                     .GET( )
                     .uri( new URI( "http://service/path/to/events" )
                     .setHeader( "Accept", "text/event-stream" )
                     .build( );

this.client.sendAsync( req, respInfo ->
{
    if ( respInfo.statusCode( ) == 200 )
    {
        return new SseSubscriber( messageData ->
        {
            // TODO: Handle messageData
        } );
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( "Request failed" );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot and will let you know if I run into any issues.

Answer (score 1):

We just built a lightweight SSE handler you can find here https://github.com/prefab-cloud/java-simple-sse-client . It leaves managing the Java HttpClient to you, and turning bytes into lines to the HttpClient's LineSubscriber so its not a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

I created one with the help of some of the other posts in this thread. It turns out that if you use some of the pre-defined methods, you don't have to deal with things like `ByteBuffer`s at all.

```java
public record ServerSentEvent(String name, String data, String id, String retry) {}


public class SseClient {

    private final HttpClient httpClient = newHttpClient();
    private final List<ServerSentEvent> receivedEvents = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public Future<?> subscribe(String url) throws IOException {
        Consumer<ServerSentEvent> eventConsumer = event -> receivedEvents.add(event);
        var bodyHandler = BodyHandlers.fromLineSubscriber(new EventstreamSubscriber(eventConsumer));
        var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(url)).GET().build();
        // After sending the request, the HttpClient will feed the response data
        // line by line to the EventstreamSubscriber (see below)
        return httpClient.sendAsync(request, bodyHandler);
    }

    public List<ServerSentEvent> getReceivedEvents() {
        return receivedEvents;
    }
}

public class EventstreamSubscriber implements Flow.Subscriber<String> {

    private Flow.Subscription subscription;
    private final List<String> bufferedLines = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Consumer<ServerSentEvent> eventConsumer;

    public EventstreamSubscriber(Consumer<ServerSentEvent> eventConsumer) {
        this.eventConsumer = eventConsumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String line) {
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            // The data stream has encountered two line breaks in a row
            // This marks the end of a server sent event
            // Therefor we map what we have collected (buffered) so far into a proper ServerSentEvent object
            ServerSentEvent serverSentEvent = mapToEvent(bufferedLines);
            // The eventconsumer then does with the event whatever it wants
            // (In this example it just adds the event to a thread safe 
            // list that the client then exposes)
            eventConsumer.accept(serverSentEvent);
            bufferedLines.clear();
        } else {
            bufferedLines.add(line);
        }
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error recieved");
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {}

    private ServerSentEvent mapToEvent(final List<String> lines) {
        Map<String, String> eventMap = lines.stream()
                .map(line -> line.split(":", 2))
                .filter(pair -> !pair[0].isEmpty())
                .collect(toMap(pair -> pair[0], pair -> pair[1], String::concat));

        return new ServerSentEvent(eventMap.get("event"), eventMap.get("data"), eventMap.get("id"), eventMap.get("retry"));
    }
}
```

I've been using it for some basic testing. It doesn't do proper error handling. If you intend to consume lots of events with it, you should alter the `eventConsumer` to not save the event to a list.

Answer (score 0):

In native Java use a `BodyHandlers.ofLines()` in your client request, that will give you a stream you can iterate on:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
      .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:5001/api/extra/generate/stream"))
      .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(bodyInString))
      .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
      .build();

Stream<String>  linesInResponse = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofLines()).body();
linesInResponse .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want to stop early and not read everything you can use anyMatch:

```
linesInResponse
.peek(System.out::println)
.anyMatch(line -> line.contains("stoppingKeyword"));
```